# Lua reference function from inside table inside of the table (Using "self" inside of table)

Tags: lua, lua-table

Let's say I have a table A and functions C and B inside of it,can I call table A function B inside of function C, by referencing self?

```
A = {
    B = function()
        print("I am B")
    end,
    C = function()
        print("I am C\nand")
        __self.B();
    end,
}
A.C();
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using the `:` method call.

```
A:C()
```

`:` is the equivalent of `A.C(A)`, but it's safer (pass the exact table reference as first argument).

Since you're defining `A.C` method inside a table constructor expression and you can't use this syntax:

```
function table:prop
```

you must declare the self feature (used as `__self` in your code) as the first parameter of the function.

```
A = {
    B = function()
        print("I am B")
    end,

    C = function(__self)
        print("I am C\nand")
        __self.B();
    end
};
```

If you don't want to specify `__self` as the first parameter, define `A.C` after assigning `A`, with this special function syntax:

```
function A:C()
    print("I am C\nand");
    self.B();
end
```

This makes the first parameter be `self`.

Comment: That's what i was looking for, Thank you

Comment: Just had to wait for cooldown till you can accept the answer.

Comment: The variable can be anything, not just __self.

Comment: @warspyking Yes, it's how it's used in the question, I'll update it anyway

Comment: Oh, I interpreted "you've to declare __self as its first parameter" as you *have* to, it's a **requirement**

Comment: @warspyking So, *you must*?

Comment: I don't think must is the proper term either tbh. It still comes across like that's a naming requirement rather than convention. Perhaps leave it as must and add a footnote explaining what you mean

Comment: @warspyking I didn't see anything wrong since I've had added a note already, but to clarify at once I made a small edit on this part, again. Evaluate it and say me if it's okay